# Capacitors and unexpected motion

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

I came across a video at Youtube recently where a plate capacitor has been placed in a vacuum , inside a metal chamber , suspended by two thin wires. Through a glass port a weak laser is directed upon the capacitor , as an indication of location .

When a high voltage $20,000V$ , is applied to the capacitor there is an eventual , displacement ; upon discharge the capacitor returns to its initial position . If this is a valid result what might be causing this , you've more or less excluded a magnetic interaction another possibility is an interaction with the metal chamber. The laser doesn't seem to be of significance.

I'm assuming that the only magnetic field present is the Earths , at $50\mu{T}$ (Tesla) this hardly seems relevant.

Video URL is:

https://youtu.be/CGN65lse5yE

Comment: See [Image dipole in front of a conducting grounded plane](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/327043).

Answer (score 2):

The field of a single charge falls off with the square of the distance, and so does the apparent size of parts of the box. So there is no net force on a charge in a metal box. However, a dipole field (like from a capacitor) falls off with the cube of the distance. So the attraction to nearer parts of the box is stronger than it is to parts farther away from the dipole. Even if the dipole is in the center of the box, it is unstable.